# jQuery datepicker only works once angularJs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, datepicker

In my `angularjs` app, I'm using `jquery datepicker` inside `div`.

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-show="!viewMode">
     <input type="text" readonly focus-me="{{ DateOfBirthFocus }}" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" ng-model="DateOfBirth" placeholder="01-jan-1991" class="form-control date-picker" ng-keydown="DateOfBirth_KeyDown($event)"  ng-blur="DateOfBirthFocus=false;" required>
</div>
```

For the first time, when I load page, it works perfectly fine, but then I hide this div using `ng-show` and show it again, datepicker does not work as required. It does not open calendar view. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16149429/2660342) but it didn't help me out. Any guesses what I'm doing wrong or what's am missing?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a working plunkr/fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the DOM element is not available at the time of jQuery initialization. Add a directive to workaround this problem:

```
myApp.directive('datePickerFoo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $(element).datepicker();

            // And optionally add based on your given link
            if (!$.datepicker.initialized) {
                $(document).mousedown($.datepicker._checkExternalClick);
                $.datepicker.initialized = true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Consider using the [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) library written by Angular's UI team. You don't need the jQuery dependency for this.